# How can I stop all rows from updating where conditions are met

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm working on an assignment for college and have a `PatientAdmissionsTbl`, it stores all patient admissions in to various wards and has a `DateDischarged` column that shows when the patient was discharged from that ward.

```
update dbo.PatientAdmissionsTbl
set DateDischarged = getdate()
where PatientID = @PatientID
and WardID = @oldWard
```

I'm using this update to try and update the last row in the table that matches these criteria, the problem I'm having is that it's updating all rows where the patient and ward id's are(past and present) in the table but I have no idea how to just limit it to updating the last row that matches it.

So, my question is how can I stop all rows being updated?

This is the table being used, rows 27-34 are the ones that matter, the DateDischarged times match up when I try to do the update above, what I want is the current time and date to be in the last row matching the where clause and just the last row not the ones above it that match... Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to word this properly

edit: DateDischarged will be NULL until that Patient is discharged, the table is then updated and the current date and time are placed in the DateDischarged column where patientid and wardid matches up with the where clause

Comment: how do you determine "last one?" is there a date or an auto number field which would enable us to determine the "last" one?  where datedistcharged is the highest for the given patentId and ward perhaps?

Comment: post your tables, most likely a table flaw. your discharge should be tied to an admission.  it is that admission that makes this unique.

Comment: none of the `order by DateDischarged desc` options will work if DateDischarged is null for the record you want to update.. that's something that needs to be specified in your question.. if the DateDischarged  is null for the last entry then just add `where DateDischarged  is null` to your update

Comment: @KM. I've added an image of the table

Comment: out of curiosity.   Would the datedischarged always be null in this case?  When you admit someone, you don't define the discharge date until they've been discharged right?  So wouldn't the date be NULL?  Which is why I ask...

Comment: @ConorS, "post your tables" not "post your table" without knowing all of your related tables it makes a solution difficult.  you should be able to discharge based on ad AdmissionID.

Comment: @xQbert The DateDischarged would be null until the patient was discharged from the ward, but the problem I was having was that one patient could have multiple admissions to a ward in the past, and my update was updating the DateDischarged for every row, past and present. Adding and DateDischarged is null to the where clause fixed, it  was just a stupid oversight on my part lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:
`and DateDischarged is null` to the where clause seems to have fixed it, I've probably made this sound more complicated than it actually was.

Answer (score 0):

One method in SQL Server is to use `TOP` with `ORDER BY`.  Assuming you want the record with the most recent date discharged:

```
with topudate as (
      select top 1 pa.*
      from dbo.PatientAdmissionsTbl pa
      where PatientID = @PatientID and WardID = @oldWard
      order by DateDischarged desc
    )
update toupdate
    set WardId = @newWard;  -- WHATEVER THE COLUMNS YOU WANT TO UPDATE WITH THEIR VALUES
```

Comment: Sorry, I've probably made my question seem a lot more complicated than it actually was lol, adding a simple: 
Where DateDischarged is null seems to have fixed it